# Grails - Connection Closed message in Tomcat 7

Tags: oracle, grails, firewall

I have a grails application that connects to an Oracle database over the firewall. I run into "Connection Closed" message.

I am not sure as to why it's happening. My production datasource is configured as follows:

```
production {
  datasource {
    dbCreate = "update"
    url = ${datasource.url}
  }
}
```

Comment: Please consider giving us more information. Is it working in dev mode ? With which database ? Is your database up and running, accessible outside grails ? Is your datasource url well configured ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't valid syntax: `url = ${datasource.url}`. It should be `url = "${datasource.url}"`. Where is `datasource.url` coming from? If it's a string, you can just use `url = datasource.url`